# What happens when we resume a suspended event from orchestration in BizTalk?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I am getting a lot of suspended events from an orchestration due to connectivity issues between BizTalk and destination system. I get 2 events, one from orchestration and another from send port, but sometimes when I resume these suspended events same request is being sent two times by BizTalk and as a result I am receiving 2 response from destination system.

Why this is happening? Shouldn't BizTalk sent only one request even if it got suspended due to some reasons? Looks to me BizTalk is re-triggering the entire process again instead of resuming from the suspended step.

Comment: It all depends on what is in the Orchestration, especially around catching exceptions, and retrying.  Without a lot more detail, we can't tell you what is going on.